# Node js. Warning: This browser doesn't support the `onScroll` event

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Использую: *React* и *griddle-react*.
При попытки создания таблицы(*Griddle*), самой простой. В консоль вылезает ошибка

> Warning: This browser doesn't support the `onScroll` event

и на странице я могу только просмотреть таблицу. Ни переход на другую страницу, ни сортировка не работает. Не пойму в чём проблема.
Вот код:

```
var React = require('react');
var DefaultLayout =  require('../layout/admin');
var Griddle = require('griddle-react');


var fakeData =  [
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Mayer Leonard",
        "city": "Kapowsin",
        "state": "Hawaii",
        "country": "United Kingdom",
        "company": "Ovolo",
        "favoriteNumber": 7
    },
    ...

];


var AdminSeason = React.createClass({
    render: function () {

        return (
            <DefaultLayout>
                <Griddle results={fakeData} />
            </DefaultLayout>
        )
    }
});
```

Comment: Это не ошибка, а предупреждение, и к проблеме, скорее всего, отношения не имеет.

Comment: Warning: Unknown DOM property class. Did you mean className?
Вот тоже предупреждение, но если его не исправить, то не получим нормально функционирующие классы у элементов.
Я так думаю тут тоже самое.

Comment: @АлександрСафронов, "Warning: This browser doesn't support the onScroll event" означает что вы используете браузер Internet Explorer 8(определение там именно по браузеру, а не по наличию евента). Не используйте этот браузер - версии IE ниже 11-й уже давно сняты с поддержки/

Comment: Вы правы. Спасибо за помощь. 
Просто использование браузера этой версии было необходимо. Но пришлось отказаться.